# remove top and right border from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to to remove the top and right border from ggplot2 graphs?

I.e, I'd like to keep the x and y-axis but remove the rest of the black frame that surrounds the graph.

//M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this thread, it deals specifically with the problem here

http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/f998d113638bf251

and gives a solution that appears to work.

Comment: The original code for the helper functions no longer work (because of updates to ggplot, I think), but Rudolf Cardinal has posted this working update: http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/extensions/rnc_ggplot2_border_themes_2013_01.r

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your plot

```
+ opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) 
+ opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank()) 
+ opts(axis.line = theme_segment())
```

Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been replaced by `theme`:

```
+ theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) 
+ theme(axis.line = element_segment())
```

Comment: I have the following function: theme_white<-function(){theme_update(panel.background=theme_blank(),panel.grid.major=theme_blank(),panel.grid.minor=theme_blank())} I added the axis.line=theme_segment() but I'm still left with black borders...I also tried the opts way but to no avail..

Comment: Maybe try to set panel.border=theme_blank() to clean all borders around the plot.

Comment: Can you upload an image so that I can maybe see where the error lies?

Comment: Finally I found it...panel.background=theme.rect(colour=NA)