# Remove grid, background color, and top and right borders from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to reproduce the plot immediately below by using ggplot2.  I can come close, but cannot remove the top and right borders.  Below I present several attempts using ggplot2, including several suggestions found on or via Stackoverflow.  Unfortunately I have not been able to get those suggestions to work.

I am hoping someone may be able to correct one or more of the code snippets below.

Thank you for any suggestions.

```
# desired plot
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
plot(a,b, bty = "l")


library(ggplot2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

# 1. ggplot2 default
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()

# 2. removes background color
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black'))

# 3. also removes gridlines
none <- theme_blank()
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none)

# 4. does not remove top and right border
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none) + opts(panel.border = none)

# 5. does not remove top and right border
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none) + opts(axis.line = theme_segment())

# 6. removes x and y axis in addition to top and right border
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458409/remove-top-and-right-border-from-ggplot2
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none) + opts(panel.background=theme_rect(colour=NA))

# 7. returns error when attempting to remove top and right border
# https://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/f998d113638bf251
#
# Error in el(...) : could not find function "polylineGrob"
#
theme_L_border <- function(colour = "black", size = 1, linetype = 1) { 
   structure( 
     function(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 1, ...) { 
       polylineGrob( 
         x=c(x+width, x, x), y=c(y,y,y+height), ..., default.units = "npc", 
         gp=gpar(lwd=size, col=colour, lty=linetype), 
       ) 
     }, 
     class = "theme", 
     type = "box", 
     call = match.call() 
   )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + opts(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none) + opts( panel.border = theme_L_border())
```

Comment: as posted in a comment below, this can now be done with + theme_classic()

Answer (score 190, accepted):

**EDIT**  Ignore this answer. There are now better answers. See the comments. Use `+ theme_classic()`

**EDIT**

This is a better version. The bug mentioned below in the original post remains (I think). But the axis line is drawn under the panel. Therefore, remove both the `panel.border` and `panel.background` to see the axis lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
df <- data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Original post**
This gets close. There was a bug with `axis.line` not working on the y-axis ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/N4dUChJ9HtU)), that appears not to be fixed yet. Therefore, after removing the panel border, the y-axis has to be drawn in separately using `geom_vline`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
df <- data.frame(a,b)

p = ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() +
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
   theme_bw() +
   opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
        panel.border = theme_blank()) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
p
```

The extreme points are clipped, but the clipping can be undone using code by [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690648/point-clipped-on-x-axis-in-ggplot).

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Or use `limits` to move the boundaries of the panel.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point() +
   xlim(0,22) +  ylim(.95, 2.1) +
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,22)) +
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(.95, 2.2)) +   
   theme_bw() +
   opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
        panel.border = theme_blank()) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

Answer (score 84):

Recent updates to ggplot (0.9.2+) have overhauled the syntax for themes.  Most notably, `opts()` is now deprecated, having been replaced by `theme()`.  [Sandy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419994/sandy-muspratt) answer will still (as of Jan '12) generates a chart, but causes R to throw a bunch of warnings.

Here's updated code reflecting current ggplot syntax:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

#base ggplot object
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b))

p +
  #plots the points
  geom_point() +

  #theme with white background
  theme_bw() +

  #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank()
  ) +

  #draws x and y axis line
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

generates:

[image: plot output]

Comment: or more simply ?   ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +  geom_point() +  theme_classic()

Comment: Neither of these approaches work for me using ggplot2 2.1.0... @wkretzsch's answer was good.

Answer (score 29):

An alternative to `theme_classic()` is the theme that comes with the [cowplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) package, `theme_cowplot()` (loaded automatically with the package). It looks similar to `theme_classic()`, with a few subtle differences. Most importantly, the default label sizes are larger, so the resulting figures can be used in publications without further modifications needed (in particular if you save them with `save_plot()` instead of `ggsave()`). Also, the background is transparent, not white, which may be useful if you want to edit the figure in illustrator. Finally, faceted plots look better, in my opinion.

Example:

```
library(cowplot)
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()
save_plot('plot.png', p) # alternative to ggsave, with default settings that work well with the theme
```

This is what the file `plot.png` produced by this code looks like:
[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the package author.

Answer (score 8):

I followed [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14629249/528691), but I also had to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/35833548 and set the x and y axes separately due to a bug in my version of ggplot (v2.1.0).

Instead of

```
theme(axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

I used

```
theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 2),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 2))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an extremely simple answer

```
yourPlot +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
    )
```

It's that easy. Source: the end of [this](https://felixfan.github.io/ggplot2-remove-grid-background-margin/) article

Answer (score 4):

Simplification from the above Andrew's answer leads to this key theme to generate the half border.

```
theme (panel.border = element_blank(),
       axis.line    = element_line(color='black'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The above options do not work for maps created with `sf` and `geom_sf()`. Hence, I want to add the relevant `ndiscr` parameter here. This will create a  nice clean map showing only the features.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = some_shp) + 
  theme_minimal() +                     # white background
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),    # remove geographic coordinates
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) + # remove ticks
  coord_sf(ndiscr = 0)                  # remove grid in the background
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be check also `panel.background`  as well.

```
 theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
```