# Removing right border from ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-grid

With the following code I can remove top and right borders along with other things. I wonder how to remove the right border of the `ggplot2` graph only.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() 

p + theme_classic()
```

Comment: it is not so easy because `panel.border` is managed as an `element_rect` object, thus it is already a rectangle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2

Comment: I agree with Davide: it may not be easily possible. I assume that theme_classic actually completely removes the box and instead draws axis lines. To illustrate this, try `p+theme(axis.line=element_line())`. It will plot `p` with the standard theme but with the axis lines added.

Comment: @lawyeR: No this is not a duplication of [stackoverflow.com/q/10861773/707145](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861773/707145).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the theme system gets in the way, but with a little twist you can hack the theme elements,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, ...)  {

  segmentsGrob(c(1,0,0),
               c(0,0,1),
               c(0,0,1),
               c(0,1,1), gp=gpar(lwd=2))
}
## silly wrapper to fool ggplot2
border_custom <- function(...){
  structure(
    list(...), # this ... information is not used, btw
    class = c("element_custom","element_blank", "element") # inheritance test workaround
  ) 

}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border=border_custom())
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Please see me edits and suggest any solution if you don't mind. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: presumably, if you apply this theme to the plots before converting them to gtable, this element should be passed along

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove both borders (as it's in the first place with `theme_classic()`), and then add one with `annotate()`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + theme_classic() + annotate(
    geom = 'segment',
    y = Inf,
    yend = Inf,
    x = -Inf,
    xend = Inf
)
```

[image: the resulting image]

(The idea is from: [How to add line at top panel border of ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256851/how-to-add-line-at-top-panel-border-of-ggplot2))

---

By the way, you of course don't need to use `theme_classic()`. If you use a theme that has different default borders, you can switch them on/off with the `theme()` function's parameters `panel.border` (sets all borders) and `axis.line` (sets separate axis "borders").

For example (for default theme):

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + annotate(
    geom = 'segment',
    y = Inf,
    yend = Inf,
    x = -Inf,
    xend = Inf
) + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line())
```

[image: the resulting image 2]