# How to add line at top panel border of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to programmatically assign a green line to the very top of my plot.

Below I demonstrate in an example what I would like, except the line is at the very bottom, instead of the top. Ideally, I would accomplish this in `theme` in a similar way.

I have tried to accomplish the top line myself with `panel.border` but it takes a `element_rect`as a parameter meaning that the other sides of the plot will also get the green line.

While it is preferable to use `theme`, I am open to using `geom_hline` or anything else. When trying to implement a solution with `geom_hline` I ran into trouble identifying  the max value of the y axis as calculated by ggplot to cleanly put the line in the same place regardless of the scale changing from plot to plot. With my real data, the scale of the y axis varies widely and has different units of measurement from plot to plot.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 data(mtcars)

 mtcars %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x= mpg, y= disp)) +
     geom_point() +
     theme(axis.line.x= element_line("green", size= 2))
```

[image: greenline]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish this with `annotate` and clever use of `Inf` values. Note that because `annotate` is drawing inside the plot and not on the axis line outside of it, you need a line of double thickness to match what you did with `theme`. The use of `Inf` values guarantees that the line will be placed at the top of the plot regardless of the scale of its units.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= mpg, y= disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = 'segment', y = Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'green', x = -Inf, xend = Inf, size = 4) +
  theme(axis.line.x= element_line("green", size= 2))
```

[image]

Further, you could save the call to `annotate` in a variable and then simply add this to plots later, if you wanted to assign the line programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

A relatively newer feature in `ggplot2` is the use of a secondary axis, which solves this a little more directly (and, imo, elegantly):

```r
gg <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= mpg, y= disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.line.x= element_line("green", size= 2))

gg + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks = NULL))
# Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

(I have not figured out how to prevent the warnings without affecting the primary axis too.)

[image: ggplot with upper line]

If you want axis ticks (albeit no labels), you can get rid of the warnings:

```r
gg + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~., labels = NULL))
```

[image: ggplot with upper line with axis ticks, no warnings]

Comment: How would I add a line at the bottom legend?

Comment: Please ask this in s new question.