# How to keep top and bottom axes in ggplot, while removing the panel border

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to keep both x axes (bottom and top), while removing the panel border (or both y axes, left and right).

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "lightgrey"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
print(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add line at top panel border of ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256851/how-to-add-line-at-top-panel-border-of-ggplot2)

Comment: No, it does not answer. I've tried ```axis.line.y.left```, ```axis.line.y.right```, ... Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Are you using `cowplot` here? `background_grid` is not found otherwise. When I run your code, my plot has a gray background and does not have the solid bottom line that yours does. Where is the code that produces this plot? (Or is this what you are hoping to create?)

Comment: Sorry for the ```cowplot``` element, it shouldn't be there. Question is corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that edit. However, I still see a gray background, different from yours. Should we just ignore that for now and focus on the axis lines?

Comment: You're right, @r2evans. It seems that with ```cowplot``` loaded, it altered ```ggplot2``` behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `sec_axis`.

In order to reproduce your white background, I'll add `theme_bw()` before the call to `theme`; this also helps me break out the lower x-axis line, then I'll add the second axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 2, linetype = "solid", colour = "lightgrey"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())

# original
p1
# both lines
p1 + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.))
```

[image: side-by-side ggplots, second with both top/bottom lines]

(side-by-side here for space/presentation, the code did not do that)

---

Side note: @chemdork123's suggested answer *does* work here: use `annotate` to add a specific geometry. While I don't prefer this method, it can suffice. (`'green'` retained from the linked answer.)

```r
p1 + annotate(geom = 'segment', y = Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'green', x = -Inf, xend = Inf, size = 4)
```

[image: alternative approach to adding a second axis line to ggplot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm changing the question to add ```theme_bw()```.