# ggplot2: y axis labels left-justified inside plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to automatically move the y-axis tick labels so that they appear left-justified *within* the actual plot area. I love the general flexibility of theme components in ggplot, but ran into a wall trying to find a general way to do this.

I know giving `axis.text.y` a combination of `hjust=0` and a negative right margin (*gag*) can accomplish this effect, but the negative margin has to be manually set to match the width of the longest y-axis tick label.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = (1:100) + runif(100, -10, 10))

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks = c(0, 30, 60, 90),
                     labels = c(0, 30, 60, "90 units of something")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0,
                                   margin = margin(0, -3.1, 0, 0, 'cm')))
```

I think it elegantly incorporates the y-axis label (e.g., `"units of something"`) into the body of the plot, but in order to accomplish it, the `-3.1` in the last line has to be found manually (by trial and error), which adds insult to injury: not only am I using a negative margin to pull text where it doesn't want to be -- I'm throwing in some arcane, fragile, hard-coded magic number.

Does anyone know where I can look for a more general and elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: crude approach but ... `ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks=c(0, 30, 60, 90)) +
  annotate("text", x=-Inf, y=c(0, 30, 60, 90),  
           label=c(0, 30, 60, "90 units of something"), hjust=0 )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())`

Comment: Thanks! I've toyed with something similar, but hate that you then lose theme control over the tick labels.

Comment: agreed, there is probably a way using ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667017/removing-right-border-from-ggplot2-graph, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123684/how-to-draw-boxes-borders-around-x-or-y-axis-labels , but a wee bit esoteric

Comment: What do you mean by "lose theme control over the tick labels"?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hack using grobs, which shifts the y-axis labels away from its original position to overlap the plot area.

While I don't consider it exactly elegant (it's a hack that requires conversion in `ggplotGrob` after all), the positioning is not hard-coded, & you can specify whatever theme control you want in `ggplot()` *before* conversion.

Setting up:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=(1:100) + runif(100, -10, 10))

# create ggplot object
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous("", 
                     breaks = c(0, 30, 60, 90),
                     labels = c(0, 30, 60, "90 units of something")) +
  # left-align y-axis labels
  # you can also specify other theme parameters as desired
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

Hack into grobs:

```
# convert from ggplot to grob object
gp <- ggplotGrob(p)

# locate the grob that corresponds to y-axis labels
y.label.grob <- gp$grobs[[which(gp$layout$name == "axis-l")]]$children$axis    

# remove y-axis labels from the plot, & shrink the space occupied by them
gp$grobs[[which(gp$layout$name == "axis-l")]] <- zeroGrob()
gp$widths[gp$layout$l[which(gp$layout$name == "axis-l")]] <- unit(0, "cm")
```

Define a new grob for the y-axis ticks / labels, with the horizontal order [ticks][labels][buffer space]:

```
# create new gtable
new.y.label.grob <- gtable(heights = unit(1, "npc"))

# place axis ticks in the first column
new.y.label.grob <- gtable_add_cols(new.y.label.grob,
                                    widths = y.label.grob[["widths"]][2])
new.y.label.grob <- gtable_add_grob(new.y.label.grob,
                                    y.label.grob[["grobs"]][[2]],
                                    t = 1, l = 1)

# place axis labels in the second column
new.y.label.grob <- gtable_add_cols(new.y.label.grob,
                                    widths = y.label.grob[["widths"]][1])
new.y.label.grob <- gtable_add_grob(new.y.label.grob,
                                    y.label.grob[["grobs"]][[1]],
                                    t = 1, l = 2)

# add third column that takes up all the remaining space
new.y.label.grob <- gtable_add_cols(new.y.label.grob,
                                    widths = unit(1, "null"))
```

Add the newly defined y-axis label grob back to the plot grob, in the same location as the plot area:

```
gp <- gtable_add_grob(gp,
                      new.y.label.grob,
                      t = gp$layout$t[which(gp$layout$name == "panel")],
                      l = gp$layout$l[which(gp$layout$name == "panel")])
```

Check result:

```
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image: result]