# Adjust datetime x-axis to shown year as a sec axis below de main axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data example:

```
structure(list(cycle_rounded = structure(c(1604188800, 1606780800, 
1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 
1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 
1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1654041600
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), media = c(27.0163533756641, 
27.3523628886565, 27.6874774847651, 27.9632663969036, 28.2324797447653, 
28.5946591329209, 28.0774171223198, 27.0218334461407, 26.3074215031224, 
25.762714516129, 25.9331010513628, 26.1019612833841, 27.4678015082705, 
27.8551394156665, 27.61177313685, 28.5468447629364, 28.6978991786281, 
29.0753629090163, NaN, NaN), desvio = c(0.349566729323312, 0.354049553514593, 
0.316576405105695, 0.28004282459359, 0.339372318521672, 0.287591989484519, 
0.312261182269958, 0.246786673478273, 0.358857114435788, 0.119453586990502, 
0.256559466294029, 0.300030737021837, 0.348529074834953, 0.383358876272664, 
0.465191392255828, 0.596852747140639, 0.324808751418437, 0.222745848411023, 
NA, NA), year = c(2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And plot at this way:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = cycle_rounded, y = media)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(y = media, ymin = media - desvio, ymax = media + desvio), 
              alpha = .2, fill = "red") +
  geom_line(col = "grey10", linewidth = .5) +
  geom_point(col = "grey10", size = 1) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m", breaks = "1 month",
                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~., sec_axis(~ ., labels = year))) +
  labs(x = "data", y = "temperatura") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, 
                                   vjust = 1, hjust = 1, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

however the sec_axis won't works as I expected.
I would like to shown years below the months as one value of year for all correspondent months.

Any helps are appreciated

Thanks,
Wilson

Comment: I think it is not clear what you exactly mean with secondary axis?

Comment: I would like the month on first row of x-axis and year in the row below. I called secondary axis to refer the row of year.

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339970/ggplot2-add-secondary-x-label-year-below-months

Comment: Included ggplot code seems to have some issues and at least form me it fails at `sec.axis`.  Perhaps include an image of what you have now and manually annotate it to illustrate what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @AdroMine exactly this, but it wont works for my data. The last month of the previous year plot above the first month of next year and the lines not connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sec_axis(~., sec_axis(~ ., labels = year))` does not make sense as a nested double-call.
2. Further, `labels=year` is either a parsing error (`'year' not found`) or it uses `year` found in the current or parent environments (whether values or a function).
3. `sec_axis` is going to put another axis on the *opposite side*, in this case the top, not as a second row.

I think we can do a single axis and put the year after a newline.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = cycle_rounded, y = media)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(y = media, ymin = media - desvio, ymax = media + desvio), 
              alpha = .2, fill = "red") +
  geom_line(col = "grey10", linewidth = .5) +
  geom_point(col = "grey10", size = 1) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = ~ { mon <- format(., format="%m"); if_else(!is.na(mon) & mon == "01", paste0(mon, format(., format = "\n%Y")), mon) },
                   breaks = "1 month") +
  labs(x = "data", y = "temperatura") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, 
                                   vjust = 1, hjust = 1, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

[image: ggplot with years under some months]

You can easily clean up that code a little by assigning the `{...}` block to a function.

I *assumed* putting the year once per 12 months, over to you do adjust this for your expectations.

Comment: Is possible to add all years that have? For example, 2020 not appear.
And adding this second row, is possible format they different, for example, use the angle as 0 and not 45°? Sorry for this aestethics questions.

Comment: It's all in the `labels=` function. Perhaps (untested) `if_else(!is.na(mon) & (mon == "01" | seq_along(mon) == which(!is.na(mon))[1]), paste0(mon, format(., format = "\n%Y")), mon)` or similar will force the first non-`NA` month to add the year to it