# Axes but no frame in histogram (R:ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axes

I'm trying to create a histogram without a frame (top and right lines), but with *x* and *y* axes shown in `R` using `ggplot`.

I am using the solution to this question: [remove grid, background color and top and right borders from ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2)

Specifically:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(faithful, aes(x=eruptions)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=0.2,colour="black",fill="white")+
    theme_bw()+theme(aspect.ratio=0.618)+
    theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

The last line, however, does not seem to have a visible effect.

To reiterate, I would like: *y*-axis shown, ticks *on* the *x*-axis, and preferably the origin of axes at (0,0).

Comment: Try using `theme_classic()` from very end of linked post. Does this give you what you want? `ggplot(faithful, aes(x=eruptions)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.2,colour="black",fill="white")+
  theme_classic() + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @TylerRinker. As far as I can tell, `faitfhul` is a built-in data frame, so the example should work for you as is. (I did add `library(ggplot2)`just to be sure.)

Comment: Thank you, @user20650. Indeed, that looks exactly like a plot I would like. This was very simple - if you consider this worthy of an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Great stuff @Fato39; please feel free to write it up an answer (and accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user20650 kindly suggested in the comments, `theme_classic()` is a simple option to do what I was trying to achieve. Additionally, to move the  *x*-axis just below the bars, `scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` can be used.

Thank you!