# ggplot2, axis not showing after using theme(axis.line=element_line())

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to draw this following graph using `ggplot2` package, but somehow the axis won't show up. the ticks are there, just not the axis line. I have used the `theme(axis.line=element_line())` function, but it wouldn't work.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = soepl_randsub, aes(x = year, y =satisf_org, group = id)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line() +ylab("Current Life Satisfaction") +theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank() ) +
    theme(panel.border= element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black", size = "2"))
```

I am not sure what went wrong. Here is the chart.

[image]

Comment: in element_line(color="black", size = "2")) replace size= "2" by size =2

Comment: if you feel like living on the bleeding edge, you can do `devtools::install_github("Katiedaisey/ggplot2")` -- or wait for the pull request to bring the fix into `hadley/ggplot2` or wait for a bug-fix release ...

Answer (score 61):

**The bug was fixed in ggplot2 v2.2.0**  There is no longer a need to specify axis lines separately.

I think this is a bug in ggplot2 v2.1.0. (See [this bug report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1567) and [this one](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1565).) A workaround is to set the x-axis and y-axis lines separately.

```
  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank() )+
  theme(panel.border= element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 2))
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify axis-size for X and Y separately. When you are specifying size="2", R is considering value 2 as non-numeric argument. Hence, axis-line parameter is **defaulted to 0 size**. Use this line of code:

`ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) + geom_point() +xlab("Date")+ylab("Value of Home")+theme_bw() +theme(plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(panel.border= element_blank()) +
         theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black", size = 2))`

> **axis_line** inherits from **line** in R, hence specifying size is mandatory for non-default values.