# Removing Results from ggplot(scatterplot) when using Geom_Point(color)

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

[image: MLS Draft Scatterplot]

I am trying to remove the grey points on my scatterplot and can't manage to do so. I have attached the lines of code that I am using below. I believe that using a subset would help but thought that the "color" in geom_point would only apply the points from the selected variables in "color"

```
ggplot(MLS_Draft_File, aes(x = MLS_Draft_File$`Overall Pick Number`, 
                           y = MLS_Draft_File$`Percentage of Minutes Played`)) +
geom_point(aes(color = MLS_Draft_File$`Drafting Club`)) + 
lims(color = c("New York City FC", "Orlando City SC", "Atlanta United FC", "Minnesota United FC", "Los Angeles FC", "FC Cincinnati"))
```

Comment: You could use a different theme, e.g. `theme_minimal()`; for more fine-tuning, you can delete/modify individual canvas/plot elements within `theme`. See e.g. [Remove grid and background from plot](https://felixfan.github.io/ggplot2-remove-grid-background-margin/)

Comment: Are you talking about grey points ? or grey background ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove grid, background color, and top and right borders from ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2)

Comment: Unrelated to issue: don't use `$` inside `aes()`. Just use the unquoted column name.

Comment: @dc37 the grey points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grey points are all clubs in your dataset that don't have a color defined by elements you passed in your function `lims`. So, to remove grey points, you can subset your dataframe to keep only clubs of interest:

```
library(ggplot2)
club <- c("New York City FC", "Orlando City SC", "Atlanta United FC", "Minnesota United FC", "Los Angeles FC", "FC Cincinnati")
ggplot(subset(MLS_Draft_File, `Drafting Club` %in% club), aes(x = `Overall Pick Number`, 
                           y = `Percentage of Minutes Played`)) +
  geom_point(aes(color =`Drafting Club`)) + 
  lims(color = club)
```

If this is not working, please consider providing a reproducible example of your dataset, see this link to know how to do it: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)