# Add specific date breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I want to add a specific date break in x axis to improve readability and to highlight important dates.

I have created a custom date vector, but this also adds gridlines which I do not want. Is there another way to do this?

```
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = as_date(c("2022-08-01", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-15", "2022-08-17", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-29")),
              date_labels = "%d %b")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having some data would help but try:

```
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = as_date(c("2022-08-01", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-15", "2022-08-17", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-29")),
              date_labels = "%d %b") +
theme(element_blank())
```

There are a number of ways to suppress/change gridlines and lots of questions on here that address this. A start: [Remove grid, background color, and top and right borders from ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2)