# theme(axis.line = element_segment(color = "Green")): Error in element_segment(color = "Green") : could not find function "element_segment"

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

In ggplot2, I am trying to make the axes have green lines.

> ```
> textMessagesLine + 
>   stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", aes(group = Group, color = Group, shape = Group)) + 
>   stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = Group, linetype = Group, color = Group)) + 
>   stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.05, aes(color = Group)) + 
>   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) +
>   labs(x = "Time", y = "Mean Grammar Score", color = "Group") + 
>   theme_classic() + 
>   theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "Blue", linewidth = 0.1), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "Red", linewidth = 0.1)) +
>   theme(axis.line = theme_segment(color = "Green"))
> ```

I am getting Error in element_segment(color = "Green") : could not find function "element_segment"

I tried using `theme(axis.line = element_segment(color = "Green"))` instead of `theme(axis.line = theme_segment(color = "Green"))` but to no avail.

[Here, it's recommended to use `theme_segment()`][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2

but this post uses `opts()` which is replaced by `theme()` but doesn't accept `theme_segment()` (or `theme_line()`).

In my original code I had used `theme_line()`, but after looking it up, I used `element_line()` here `theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "Blue", linewidth = 0.1), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "Red", linewidth = 0.1))`, which worked.

Do you have any suggestions as to how to use the segment option?

Comment: Try with `element_line`. The post you referenced is pretty old and the answer which uses `theme_segment`, `theme_blank`, ... will no longer work with more recent versions of ggplot2. In general you could have a look at `?theme` to lookup the type of `element_xxx` you have to pass to a theme element, e.g. for `axis.line` this is `element_line`.

Comment: @stefan, thanks for your replying! You're right, I should have looked up `?theme`. I am studying from a textbook from 2018. It seems that `element_segment` or `theme_segment` doesn't exist anymore.