# ggplot2 - remove panel top border

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm want to remove only the top part of my graph. 
I found some directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861773/remove-grid-background-color-and-top-and-right-borders-from-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458409/remove-top-and-right-border-from-ggplot2). However, they remove all the borders or the top and left. 
I know that I should probably use the argument `panel.border` with `element_blank()` or `element_rect()` but I cannot find the correct way to define it.

**I'm looking for this**:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  jtools::theme_apa() + 
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank())
```

Will results with:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One more option (with some advice from Tjebo)

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .))+
  jtools::theme_apa() +
  theme(
    axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(color = 'black'),
    axis.line.y.left   = element_line(color = 'black'),
    axis.line.y.right  = element_line(color = 'black'),
    axis.text.y.right  = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    panel.border       = element_blank())
```

Comment: if you now remove the right axis text and tick marks, you're almost there ;) +1

Comment: Thank you! even though it's a workaround I prefer it over loading other script/pkgs.

Answer (score 5):

Using one of the references you have posted, you end up in [this](http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/extensions/rnc_ggplot2_border_themes_2013_01.r) script (thanks to Rudolf Cardinal and Alex Holcombe). You can use the function `theme_border()` to plot the borders you want. To do so, just download the script provided in the link, put it in your working directory and execute the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
source("rnc_ggplot2_border_themes_2013_01.r")
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  jtools::theme_apa() + 
  theme(
    panel.border = theme_border(type = c("bottom","right","left")))
```

[image: plotwithoutborders]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it's actually a really good work around. My only problem was that I need to read additional script and the fact that it loads many variables to my environment. They should make it as a package! :)

Comment: Error in theme_border(type = c("bottom", "left")) : 
  could not find function "theme_border"

Answer (score 4):

Another option is a massive cheat... Use theme_classic and add a segment

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  #jtools::theme_apa() + 
  theme_classic() +
  annotate(geom = 'segment', x= Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = Inf)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you you for your answer, but I have other theme(s) setting that I use which clashes with your answer.